# Trying to create RDD from external dataset(word_list.txt) but getting error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

```
valfile = sc. textFile("/Users/Downloads/word_list-1.txt")My_file: org.apache.spark.rdd. RDD[String] = /Users/Downloads/word_list-1.txt Mappartitions RDD[1] at textFile at <console>:23
```

Getting an error:

> ';' expected but '=' found.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please fix your question / formatting. I have no idea what you attempted to do, but it failed badly.